# Задача по типизации функции call

Tags: typescript

Вашему вниманию задача из книги *Профессиональный TypeScript. Разработка масштабируемых JavaScript-приложений*. Мне эта задача показалась интересной и применимой на практике.

> Дана функция:
>
> ```
> function call<T extends unknown[], R>(
>     f: (...args: T) => R,
>     ...args: T
> ): R {
>     return f(...args)
> }
> ```
>
> Обновите реализацию `call`, чтобы она работала только для функций, чей второй аргумент является `string`. Для остальных функций реализация должна проваливаться при компиляции.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, что означает метка "typescript-task" у вашего вопроса?

Comment: Для этого вполне достаточно метки "typescript".

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю своё [решение](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigcgCoQM7DQbgChCAzAVwDsBjYASwHsKoq4AbVgHgyggA9gIFACbYoAbUoBrCvQDuFADRRcAJ1oUA5koB0uqTPliAukaUAlAHwAKQlDtQSALihXd2uCo3ZnGAJRRkCygzBVt7Nw8vH0JfZzMoAG8wuxUIYDIVJhJXXUjsX0IAX2JyajpGKAFcK1ZBDWAAC2cKMgQAIwgVJQA3NjIIZ1V1DVjlYDVNY0TkqFT0zKgAQRUVOBBtEhV6BCsEqFrNRqhCpSt-QKhe1n6C4tJKGgYmKuAAJhq6xubWjq7LvoGYwmWkqOGAzja9HotTgFFGQ0mRmm9lmaQyTGWq3Wm22u32nwax1O5yCVxuRRKD3KzzBAGYPocmlAWu1Oj0Ad9WX8XhCoTC4ZzflMkii5uilis1hstjs9gd6oSTi4Sf9rhBbpSyk9QbgACwMhWCtmq-qDcbDJQ8qCQ6EQWGWsGvZzwJDw82I5H2MULTFSnGy-GMonKgKkgEawi1YBQOABZhsVhWF5KACMAAYlGg4GhfEQo9a4yx2EnHamM%20hs5aVDciIQAPR1qAAAWA2AAtHxIDQOyt6CpI2lmIWEyXcLSy0pdbmB9GUPHiy9dRP0Ggq-1M1hcDn8EA):

```js
// Тип для теста
type Name = 'Test';

function call<T extends [unknown, string, ...unknown[]], R>(
    f: (...args: T) => R,
    ...args: T
): R {
    return f(...args)
}

function test(length: number, value: string): string[] {
    return Array.from({ length }, () => value)
}

function test2(length: number, value: string, test: boolean): string[] {
    return Array.from({ length }, () => value)
}

function test3(length: number, value: number, test: boolean): number[] {
    return Array.from({ length }, () => value)
}

function test4(length: number, value: string, test: boolean, test2: Name): string[] {
    return Array.from({ length }, () => value)
}

let a = call(test, 10, 'a');
let b = call(test2, 10, 'a', true);

// @ts-expect-error
let c = call(test3, 10, 4);
let e = call(test4, 10, '', true, 'Test');
```

Не стесняйтесь предложить другие решения.